# How to pass custom value to existing function (without changing function)?

Tags: javascript, angular, function, parameters

My angular app has a function (on a different file) that loads a script. I need to load a different script in one case, but utilize the same function. I was told not to touch or add to the existing function but instead "just call it with my values".  Not sure what that means exactly :-/

```
loadScript (url = 'assets/scripts/external/foo.js') {
    let body: any = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    let script: any = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

Something like this on my file but I'm thinking but striking out...

```
 url = 'assets/scripts/external/bar.js'
 loadScript (this.url);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish what your want. I think you're getting thrown off by this:

`loadScript (url = 'assets/scripts/external/foo.js')`

Whenever you see something like `myVar = 'some value'` in a `function` as an argument, that just means it's the default value (if nothing is passed in).

```
  loadScript (url = 'assets/scripts/external/foo.js') {
    let body: any = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    let script: any = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

You should be able to call `loadScript(<whatever>)` and it should work just fine

Simplified example:

```js
function test(myValue = 1) {
  return myValue;

}

console.log('Should be 1', test());
console.log('Should be 2', test(2));
```

So, as you can see, you can accomplish what you want without changing the function at all (*assuming you're giving us the full context here*)

Comment: Yes - I thought I had to explicitly override the value in the original function, and was making it harder on myself.    Thank you for the great explanation and simplified example - it's working!

Answer (score 0):

U can just:

```
     loadScript (var, url = 'assets/scripts/external/foo.js') {
        let body: any = 
         document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        let script: any = document.createElement('script');
       script.type = 'text/javascript';
       script.src = url;
       body.appendChild(script);
       Console.log(var)
       }
```

You just pass a second argument

Comment: Thanks - I was specifically asked not to change the function itself though -  instead call the function on my page with my  custom value  somehow...

Comment: Your code is invalid. `var` is a reserved word in javascript and `Console.log` is not a function in javascript. Not to mention, OP strictly mentioned they cannot change function code and your answer says to do so.